# BindingResolutionException in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I am trying to bind interface to implementation.
I have created an interface in app\Contracts\Services\LoginServiceContract.php

```
namespace App\Contracts\Services;

interface LoginServiceContract{

    ...

}
```

Service in app\Services\LoginService.php

```
namespace App\Services;

use App\Contracts\Services\LoginServiceContract;

    class LoginService extends Service implements LoginServiceContract{
        ...
    }
```

LoginService extends Service class which is also in same namespace as LoginService.

I have bind the LoginServiceContract to LoginService in AppServiceProvider.php in register method as below:

```
public function register()
{

    $this->app->bind( 'App\Contracts\Services\LoginServiceContract', 'App\Services\LoginService' );

}
```

And LoginController.php contains:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API\V1;

use App\Contracts\Services\LoginServiceContract;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller{

    private $loginService;

    public function __construct( LoginServiceContract $loginService ){

        $this->loginService = $loginService;

    }

    public function index( Request $request ){

        $this->loginService->session( $request );

    }

}
```

When I make a request to LoginController@index, following error occurs:

```
BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 873:
Target [App\Contracts\Services\LoginServiceContract] is not instantiable while building [App\Http\Controllers\API\V1\LoginController].
```

I have tried following commands in terminal:

- php artisan clear-compiled
- php artisan cache:clear
- composer dump-autoload

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: please add the contructor of LoginService in his own code

Comment: @dparoli, I not getting what you are trying to say. Can you please explain it little more?

Comment: do LoginService or his parent have a function named __construc()? if yes can you please post the __construct() function code.

Comment: No. I don't have __construct() method implemented in both Service and LoginService class

Comment: please try to declare `private $loginService;` as `public`

Comment: Tried it. Still not working.